# Check if the array results from two database tables does not match

Tags: laravel

I am trying to fetch array data from two tables columns and compare if it matches. If the two results are the same return a message and if not save the form data to the database.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
       
        $ttn_number = DB::select('select number from test_tracking_number');
        $ttn_code = DB::select('select ttn_code from tests');
     
        if ($ttn_code = $ttn_number) {
            $msg = "TTN CODE HAS ALREADY BEEN USED";
             return Redirect::back()->with('success',$msg);
        }
        else{
        
        $test = new Tests();
        $test->ttn_code = request('ttn_code');
        $test->save();
    }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

I have tried using the above functions but it's not comparing it. Kindly  help

Comment: `ttn_code = $ttn_number` to `ttn_code == $ttn_number` don't assign compare it with `==`

Comment: @KamleshPaul its not comparing

Comment: then check `dd($ttn_code)` and `dd($ttn_number)` what inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, `DB::select` returns array of stdClass objects.

Also change `=` with `===`.

And your final code:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
       
    $ttn_number = DB::select('select number from test_tracking_number')[0]->number ?? null;
    $ttn_code = DB::select('select ttn_code from tests')[0]->ttn_code ?? null;
     
    if ($ttn_code === $ttn_number) {
        $msg = "TTN CODE HAS ALREADY BEEN USED";

        return Redirect::back()->with('success',$msg);
    } else {
        $test = new Tests();
        $test->ttn_code = request('ttn_code');
        $test->save();
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Totally recommend rewrite the code and don't answer the `xy problem` questions.

Good luck.

Comment: if I want to list all arrays instead of one[0]?

Comment: @Edwin what's your point? What you want to do? Try to describe the task and we will try to help you. :)